# unexpected print output MIPS assembly palindrome checker

Tags: assembly, mips, palindrome

I have been working on a palindrome checker program using in assembly using PLP tool.  I am having an issue getting the program to print the expected output.  The program accepts string inputs with a period "." as terminating character.  It should check each word and return yes if it is a palindrome (1 stored in $a0) or no (0 stored in $a0). Right now all I can get it to do is print no regardless of output.  I have been debugging this thing for 2 weeks now and can't figure out what is wrong.  I could desperately use some help.  Here a few examples of inputs and outputs (expected vs actual).  Thank you so much for you time and insight.

Entry:  abba.
Actual: no
Expected: yes

Entry:  racecar. abba. test.
Actual: no no no
Expected: yes yes no

```
.org 0x10000000
#Initializations
li $sp, 0x10fffffc  # Starting address of empty stack
li $s0, 0xf0000000  # UART base address
li $s1, array_ptr   # Array head pointer
li $s2, array_ptr   # Array tail pointer
j main
nop

array_ptr:          # Label pointing to 100 word array
    .space 100
    move $s2, $s1

main:
    jal poll_UART
    nop
    jal period_check
    nop
    jal space_check
    nop
    jal case_check
    nop
    jal array_push
    nop
    j main
    nop

#The "poll_UART function should poll the status register of the UART.
#If the 2^1 bit position (ready bit) is set to 1 then it 
# should copy the receive buffer's value into $v0 and send
# a clear status command (2^1) to the command register before
# returning (return statement is already included)

poll_UART:

    lw $t1, 4($s0)
    li $t2, 0b10
    and $t3, $t1, $t2
    beq $t3, $0, main
    nop
    lw $v0, 8($s0)
    sw $t2, 0($s0)
    jr $ra
    nop

# The "period_check" function should check if the current character ($v0)
# is a period ("."). If it is a period then the function should go to the
# label, "palindrome_check". If the character is not a period then it
# should use the included return.

period_check:

    li $t0, 0x2E
    beq $v0, $t0, palindrome_check
    nop

    # The "space_check" function should check if the current character ($v0)
    # is a space (" "). If it is then it should jump to "main" so
    # that it skips saving the space character. If not it should
    # use the included return.

space_check:

    li $t4, 0x20
    beq $t4, $v0, main
    jr $ra
    nop

# The "case_check" function should check if the current character ($v0)
# is a lowercase character (i.e. greater than the ASCII value of 'Z').
# If it is then it should convert the value of $v0 to the uppercase
# equivalent before returning. If it is already uppercase then it
# should skip converting and return.

case_check:

    li $t5, 0x5A
    slt $t6, $v0, $t5
    li $t7, 1
    beq $t6, $t7, convert
    convert:
    addiu $v0, $v0, -32
    jr $ra
    nop


    # The "array_push" function should save the current character ($v0) to the
    # current location of the tail pointer, $s2. Then it should increment the
    # tail pointer so that it points to the next element of the array. Last
    # it should use the included return statement.
    
    array_push:
    
        sw $v0, 0($s2)
        addiu, $s2, $s2, 4
        jr $ra
        nop
    
    # The "palindrome_check" subroutine should be jumped to by the period
    # check function if a period is encountered. This subroutine should contain 
    # a loop that traverses the array from the front towards the back (using the
    # head pointer, $s1) and from the back towards the front(using the tail
    # pointer, $s2). If the string is a palindrome then as the array is traversed
    # the characters pointed to should be equal. If the characters are not equal
    # then the string is not a palindrome and the print function should be used
    # to print "No". If the pointers cross (i.e. the head pointer's address is
    # greater than or equal to the tail pointer's address) and the compared
    # characters are equal then the string is a palindrome and "Yes" should be
    # printed. 
    # 
    # Remember to restore the head and tail pointers to the first element
    # of the array before the subroutine jumps back to main to begin processing the
    # next string. Also, keep in mind that because the tail pointer is updated at
    # the end of "array_push" it technically points one element past the last
    # character in the array. You will need to compensate for this by either
    # decrementing the pointer once at the start of the array or using an offset
    # from this pointer's address.
```

palindrome_check:

```
addiu $s2, $s2, -8 
move $s3, $s1
subu $s6, $s2, $s3
beq $s6, $0, palindrome
nop
check_loop:
lw $s4, 0($s3)
lw $s5, 0($s2)
bne $s5, $t0, not_palindrome
nop
adjust_pointers:
addiu $s2, $s2, -4
addiu $s3, $s3, 4 
slt $t8, $s3, $s2
bne $t8, $t0, check_loop
nop
j palindrome
nop
palindrome:
li $a0, 1
call project3_print
move $s2, $s1
j main 
not_palindrome:
li $a0, 0
call project3_print 
move $s2, $s1
j main 
nop
```

Comment: One obvious oddity is that in your `check_loop` you read a word from memory into `$s4`, and then never use `$s4` in any other instruction.

Comment: Also, you say that you've spent a lot of time debugging your code, but it's not clear exactly what this debugging consisted of. You don't mention any observations that you've made while debugging. If I was trying to find what the problem was, I'd probably set a breakpoint at the start of the `palindrome_check` function, verify that all inputs looked ok, and then single-step through the entire function, making sure to verify at each instruction that the contents of all registers are what I expect them to be (and the same for all memory being accessed).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I think I almost have it sorted out.  How would you go about resetting the pointers back to their original locations to begin processing the next incoming string ?

Comment: If the problem is purely about the palindrome subroutine, you can improve the question by eliminating the irrelevant, presumably working boilerplate of splitting up input. See [mcve].